# Docker container can't find an installed node dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I start up my docker container it can't find one of my installed dependencies. I've tried removing my build + node_modules folder, going into my docker container terminal and running `yarn list` and searching for the dependency there (it is). I've also tried running `yarn add <dependency` and it says it works, but still throws the error `error TS2307: Cannot find module '<dependency>' or its corresponding type declarations.`

It works fine locally, just not on docker.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS dev

WORKDIR /app
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY package.json ./
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/api
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

And my docker compose:

```
services:
  api:
    profiles: ['api', 'web']
    container_name: slots-api
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
      target: dev
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 9229:9229 # for debugging
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/api
      - /app/node_modules/ # do not mount node_modules
      - /app/api/node_modules/ # do not mount node_modules
    depends_on:
      - database
    command: yarn dev
```

Comment: You copy your package.json into the folder /app but run the `yarn install` in the folder /app/api, so there would be nothing to install . Also it could help to also add your package.json and list what files are in your current dir and are coppied with `copy . .`

Comment: @mszalbach Thank you! I switched around my build and dev commands to all be from root, and I cleared all my docker cache (112 gigs ) and it's working now!

Comment: I will debug new my docker image like this: `docker run -it my-docker sh`, then check something, like folder or others,

Comment: Try deleting the entire `volumes:` block.  The path-only syntax does not mean "do not mount"; instead, it causes Docker to mount an anonymous volume over `node_modules` and to ignore the image contents, which in turn means it will ignore changes in `package.json`.  That sounds like what you're seeing.